# PROC MEANS - Save table shown in results and not in Output Data

Tags: sas, mean, proc

I have the following code to produce descriptive statistics:

```
proc means data=sashelp.cars;
    var Horsepower Weight Length;
    output out =  cars_stats mean = std = /autoname;
run;
```

I would like to get the table shown in the Results tab in the Output Data as I export the tables to Excel later on.

At the moment I get the following in the results:

[image: Table I want to get out]

But I get this in the Output Data tab. 
[image: Table I get in Output Data]

How could I get the table from the Results in the Output Data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Proc MEANS` with option `STACKODSOUTPUT` will produce the same desired table.

```
ods select none;
proc means data=sashelp.cars stackodsoutput;
    var Horsepower Weight Length;
    ods output summary = cars_stats_stacked;
run;
ods select all;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`ods` to the rescue!

First run your code like this:

```
ods trace on;
proc means data=sashelp.class;
    var Weight Height;
    output out =  class_stats mean = std = /autoname;
run;
ods trace off;
```

Then check the log:

```
Output Added:
-------------
Name:       Summary <-- We want this bit
Label:      Summary statistics
Template:   base.summary
Path:       Means.Summary
-------------
```

Then re-run like this:

```
ods select none;
ods output summary = class_summary;
proc means data=sashelp.class;
    var Weight Height;
    output out =  class_stats mean = std = /autoname;
run;
ods select all;
```

This approach allows you to capture any output from any proc that would normally be displayed in the results area as a sas dataset instead.